# BMP C library to open and save image

Tags: software-recommendation, libraries, c, image-processing

Can anyone recommend me a C library for loading and saving .bmp images. I need to load the image, edit some bits, and then save it. I have found the DevIl library, but I can't find the way to use it in Ubuntu.

I'm a beginner so I would appreciate instructions on the whole process from downloading the library, using it in my code for loading and saving, to compiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use libgraphicsmagick in C, download the library and the header using apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install libgraphicsmagick1-dev
```

Now you have the headers installed, you should be able to use the library in your C code:

```
#include <magick/api.h>
```

Please see the API documentation for further programming examples and help: http://www.graphicsmagick.org/api/api.html